# How can I get this datetime format in java

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, datetime-format

I follow this api [document](https://help.aliyun.com/document_detail/27487.html), this api need a Date header, they said they only support GMT date format, so I tried all bellow, but no one success.

```
@Test
public void testFormat(){
    Date a = new Date("Tue, 08 Dec 2015 06:13:40 GMT");
    System.out.println(a);
    Date b = new Date("Thu, 17 Mar 2012 18:49:58 GMT");
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(b.toGMTString()); // 17 Mar 2012 18:49:58 GMT
    System.out.println(b.toLocaleString());// 2012-3-18 2:49:58
    System.out.println(DateFormatUtils.ISO_8601_EXTENDED_DATETIME_TIME_ZONE_FORMAT.format(b));//2012-03-18T02:49:58+08:00
}
```

So, what's the format like this `Tue, 08 Dec 2015 06:13:40 GMT`, how can I get this format in Java ?

**EDIT**

Output

```
Tue Dec 08 14:13:40 CST 2015
Sun Mar 18 02:49:58 CST 2012
17 Mar 2012 18:49:58 GMT
2012-3-18 2:49:58
2012-03-18T02:49:58+08:00
```

I'm not just asking the pattern, I was wondering is there any standard or name for this format ?

Comment: Pleasae edit your question and add the output from quoted code

Comment: See the `SimpleDateFormat` docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What's the format like this `Tue, 08 Dec 2015 06:13:40 GMT`? Is there any standard or name for it?**

[The doc of `Date.parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse-java.lang.String-) refers to it as “the IETF standard date syntax”. [That of `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) as “RFC 1123 / RFC 822”. The latter is a lot newer so probably more current.

**How can I get this format in Java?**

It is built-in as [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME). For example, on my computer `OffsetDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)` just produced

```
Thu, 6 Apr 2017 15:25:44 +0200
```

The classes I use are in the `java.time` package. They are built in with the Java 8 I am using. On Android you can get the `java.time` classes in [the ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The zone offset in the above output was `+0200`. What if I want it to be `GMT`? Just use `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)`, and it will be. More generally, make sure your `OffsetDateTime` is in the UTC offset. Alternatively, use `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)`; this will override the zone of your `OffsetDateTime`.

If you don’t want a dependency on ThreeTenABP, I believe Zaki Pathan’s comment gives you the solution for Android.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SimpleDateFormat` class. Pass the correct pattern and you can get any output you want to be honest.
There is documentation for the function you should refer to 
[Java Doc Simple Date Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)